# Merge values of a dataframe where other columns match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe storing a date, car_brand, color and a city:

```
 date              car_brand    color     city
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      red       paris
 "2020-01-02"      prosche      red       paris
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      red       london
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      red       paris
 "2020-01-05"      porsche      red       london
 "2020-01-01"      audi         blue      munich
 "2020-01-02"      audi         red       munich
 "2020-01-03"      audi         red       london
 "2020-01-04"      audi         red       london
 "2020-01-05"      audi         red       london
```

I now want to create from that a dataframe in the following way:
Merge rows together where for consecutive days the car_brand, color and city match. So in the example I want to end up with a dataframe

```
 date                             car_brand    color     city
 ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02"]      porsche      red       paris
 ["2020-01-03"]                   porsche      red       london
 ["2020-01-04"]                   porsche      red       paris
 ["2020-01-05"]                   porsche      red       london
 ["2020-01-01"]                   audi         blue      munich
 ["2020-01-02"]                   audi         red       munich
 ["2020-01-03","2020-01-05"]      audi         red       london
```

How can I achieve that? I tried with pd.concat and pd.merge but nothing worked so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If consecutive is important can check in list comprehension.  This is an extension of technique to get a `list` from a `lambda` function on a group.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(""" date              car_brand    color     city
 "2020-01-01"      porsche      red       paris
 "2020-01-02"      porsche      red       paris
 "2020-01-03"      porsche      red       london
 "2020-01-04"      porsche      red       paris
 "2020-01-05"      porsche      red       london
 "2020-01-01"      audi         blue      munich
 "2020-01-02"      audi         red       munich
 "2020-01-03"      audi         red       london
 "2020-01-04"      audi         red       london
 "2020-01-05"      audi         red       london"""), sep="\s+")
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df = (
    df
    .groupby([c for c in df.columns if c!="date"])["date"]
    # only include if first date or if it's a consequetive date
    .agg(lambda x: [xx for i,xx in enumerate(x) if i==0 or xx==(list(x)[i-1]+pd.DateOffset(1))])
    .reset_index()
)
```

### output

```
car_brand color   city                                                            date
     audi  blue munich                                           [2020-01-01 00:00:00]
     audi   red london [2020-01-03 00:00:00, 2020-01-04 00:00:00, 2020-01-05 00:00:00]
     audi   red munich                                           [2020-01-02 00:00:00]
  porsche   red london                                           [2020-01-03 00:00:00]
  porsche   red  paris                      [2020-01-01 00:00:00, 2020-01-02 00:00:00]
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately I get the error ValueError: Function does not reduce

Comment: with sample data or your actual data set?   whet version of python & pandas are you using?

Comment: With the sample data, Python 3.6.9, Pandas version '0.22.0'

Comment: Updating the pandas version did the trick thanks!

Comment: That's quite an old version of pandas.  I'm using 1.2.0, 0.22.0 is failing to install in my virtual env.  Can you try with uptown date version of pandas?  I'll build an env that matches yours but will take some time

Comment: Updating the pandas already did the trick :)